# Please recommend a motherboard for budget gaming build

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

I am considering a budget gaming build. The graphic card probably will be GTX 950 or even less powerful (well, let's just suppose I'm buying a GTX950 card).

Please recommend a motherboard, my requirements are

1. It should be powerful enough to fully exploit the potential of GTX 950, that is, I won't blame the motherboard for running a game slowly
2. It should supports DDR4 memory
3. At least I have heard of the maker of that motherboard, include ASUS, GIGABYTE, MSI, ASRock or EVGA
4. It should be a budget motherboard, let's say under 100$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43700/discussion-on-question-by-shintaroid-intel-h110-chipset-motherboard-or-h170-fo).

Comment: I think it might be wise to ask for recommendations on some of the other components first (e.g. CPU, GPU and case), as they will provide more requirements for the motherboard. Some requirements you can add to your question: How many USB ports do you expect to use? What type of internet connectivity (wired or wireless, what speed)? What games are you planning on playing at what settings?

Comment: Also, unfortunately, you are currently limited to Intel CPUs if you insist on DDR4 support, and you may wish till AMD releases Zen, in which case you'd probably only want a GPU and case recommendation. The reason I'm suggesting you wait till the release of Zen is that AMD typically has better budget options for gaming.

Comment: @Alpha3031 Thanks for your comments. In fact I'm quite interested in Zen, but I still have to wait for several months, it's always tantalizing to buy a new rig when I do have many excuses. Anyway I will try, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Hi I hope this helps you regarding your question if graphics card will used its full potential on pcie 3.0 yes of course especially with the new graphics card that are out today from nvidia and amd. I want to add somethind if your planning to buy gpu try gt1060 from nvidia or rx 470 crossfire from amd. 600 or 700W power supply will be enough for it.

Try looking for this link also.
https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Z170-H170-H110-B170-Q150-Q170---What-is-the-Difference-635/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact I'm considering a budget build, and what i can afford is like GTX 950 or even RX 460. As far as I know, it is well enough to fully exploit the performance of that class GPU run at even PCIe 2.0 x8 mode. However, as I mentioned in my Question, it seems that the H110 chipset only supports PCIe 2.0 up to x4, which I'm very concerned if the chipset can handle a GPU like GTX 950.

Comment: @shintaroid The short answer is that while the chipset itself supports 6 PCIe 2.0, there are also 16 lanes of PCIe 3.0 coming off the CPU. H110 chipset motherboards therefore do support the operation of a dedicated GPU, however, you should probably check with the specific motherboard manufacturer to be certain. If you are on a low budget, you might want to consider waiting for AMD to release Zen based consumer CPUs. Is there any specific reason you want DDR4 support?

Comment: @Alpha3031 Thanks! So I don't have to worry about the chipset so long as motherboard provides PCIe 3.0 slot, great! For DDR4, cause it's the newest standard, and affordable compared with CPU or GPU, I decide to give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: The question is about which motherboard to buy... the GPUs you're referencing are called the GTX 1060 and the RX 470 (no "crossfire" in title). Either one of those cards will run perfectly fine on a ~450W PSU with the vast majority of modern CPUs. Crossfire and SLI are really not good choices for budget systems for a lot of reasons.

Comment: @Alpha3031 and shintaroid, I'd appreciate your input on this question over at http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/539/should-this-question-be-taken-off-hold

Comment: @AdamWykes Wow, thanks for your discussion in META, since I don't have enough reputation to add comment there, I just comment here. Right now I am working, so when I go home I will further edit my question to see if it will satisfy the question rule. Thank you!

Comment: Well i'm sorry if I included crossfire in AMD RX 470 yes I know that there is no crossfire in the gpu. And yes I notice that the user is on budget build but what I want to say is when the user tries to buy a gaming build not a budget one he/she can consider crossfire the rx 470. Thank you for your reply Adam Wykes I myself is an IT Technical Support from a company and I am new with this community.